# How do I get an Apple Developer Certificate / Private Key?

Tags: xcode, macos

I could not find a canonical question on the process of obtaining an Apple Developer certificate for use with signing of OSX .pkg files.

How can I obtain an Apple Developer Certificate for signing OSX Packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Navigate to the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/)
- Click "Certificates, Identities and profiles"
  [image: Certificates, Identities and profiles]
- Select "OSX" from the Dropdown  [image: OSX]
- In the "Certificates" section Click the "+" Symbol, and follow the wizard to generate a CSR request.  The wizard will have you generate the request in Keychain, and then download your private key.

You can now use this key to sign packages in Xcode / various packaging tools.

You can also use the [`productsign`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html) utility to sign existing packages:

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: John Smith (MYH4SH)" mypackage.pgk mypackaged_signed.pkg
```

More about [Certificates on other Apple Platforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)